# Java: How to initialize a fixed length List of List?

Tags: java, sql, list, fixed-length-record

I have a list of String[] that contains some data returned from a database

```
List<String[]> x;
```

Now for each "x" I have to store its relative Ys. (Imagine that "x" contains the elements returned from a "SELECT DISTINCT xColumn1, xColumn2 FROM table" and now for each element I have to store the data from another query).

Y's elements are going to be stored here:

```
List<List<String[]>> yElements;
```

I've read that I can declare a fixed length list, but I don't know how. This is what I have done:

```
yElements = Arrays.asList(new List<String[]>[x.sixe()]);
```

Netbeans told me "generic array creation" error.

I also want to tell you that I MUST have a fixed lenght list to store a List of String[ ] in a  specific index of this List of Lists. (If you can show me how to do with an array it would be great, too!)
Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you'd be better of with a bean to keep things together: `List<XandY>` with `class XandY { String xColumn1; String xColumn2; Something y;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your lists to be absolutely fixed size, you could use the native arrays. They can be multi-dimensional so for example you can have `String[][] x` or `String[][][] y'.

Honestly however, your approach is a bit confusing and not that crisp from a design point of view.

Why not, similarly to as was suggested in the comment, have an object which has both columns (xColumn1, xColumn2), and then have the Y elements in a separate object, which can then be associated with the first one?

so:

```
class XDetails
{
   String xColumn1;
   String xColumn2;

   YDetails relatedY;
   ...
}

class YDetails
{
   ... fields of Y ...

}
```

Then you can have an array or `List<XDetails>`

Comment: This is what I've done:
`class A
{
String[] xColumn;
private Yelements[] yElements;
}

class Yelements
{
List<String[]> yElements;
}
`

Now works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an instance of an array of a generic type using `new`.

One alternative is this:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        List<String[]> x = ...;
        List<List<String[]>> yElements = Arrays.asList(
                (List<String[]>[])Array.newInstance(List.class, x.size()));
    }
}
```

Related question: [How to create a generic array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/java-how-to-generic-array-creation).  (The example there is about creating an instance of an array of a generic type parameter ... but the same approach applies here.)

---

However, I think that this whole question is based on an incorrect assumption.

> I also want to tell you that I MUST have a fixed lenght list to store a List of String[ ] in a specific index of this List of Lists.

You don't HAVE TO have a fixed sized list.  From the computational perspective, your code would work just fine with a non-fixed sized list ... provided that you don't add or remove list elements.  (In fact, using `Arrays.asList` to wrap an array won't stop some other code *trying* to add / remove elements ...)  Anyway ... if you just make the implementation type `ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>`, then the generic array creation problem goes away.

In addition, I suspect that it is incorrect to use `x.size()` as the size of `yElements`.  The size of `yElements` probably should be determined by the number of `x` instances there are going to be, not the size of a given `x` instance.

Comment: I "have to" because of my implementation in threads and, yes, x.size() is the correct length but I have to admit that probably I was not so much clear to describe my problem :)
BTW, Thank you for your time. The first part of your comment is very interesting!